# AWS - How to reboot or restart EC2 instance from CloudWatch Alarm?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

Sometimes my application dies without any reason and I can detect that using CloudWatch and CPU usage metric going down.

At this moment I want to restart the java application or the whole EC2 instance.

Any suggestions how can I achive that?

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48199663/auto-reboot-an-aws-ec2-instance-at-midnight

Answer (score 4):

[AWS CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/) now provides a [reboot EC2 instance action](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-cloudwatch-action-reboot-ec2-instance/).

Answer (score 2):

You can let CloudWatch terminate your EC2 instance and let AutoScaling bring up another "fresh" instance with your application configured.

Answer (score 0):

If only your application halt but EC2 instance works.

You could write a shell monitor the app using CloudWatch API and shoot the app when necessary,then make it a task in cron. Or you can using a shell right in your EC2 instance.

To restart your EC2 instance automatically is way too dangerous ,you can try Autoscaling, which automatically starts a new instance when your instance frozen and keep your SLA.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure in **Cloudwatch Alarm EC2 Action** for reboot the instance.

Screenshot:
[image]

References:

- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-cloudwatch-action-reboot-ec2-instance/