# How to restart an application, running on EC2 instance, when Cloudwatch alarm triggers?

Tags: events, amazon-ec2, alarm, amazon-cloudwatch

My current set up has AWS Couldwatch alarm triggering the sending of an email notification when, eg. CPU usage is below x% for n minutes.  This is easy enough to set up through the AWS Management Console.  However, under this arrangement, I then need to remote login into the instance and restart my failed application manually.  I'd like to automate this with the same Cloudwatch alarm event, instead triggering the running of a script (on the same EC2 instance as my application) which would then restart my application. How to do this?

If there is a way to catch the Cloudwatch alarm event from within the instance running the application, then this might be an easy way to proceed, but I can't find out how to do that.

There is a similar question posted here ([How to restart EC2 instance from CloudWatch alarm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13389737/how-to-restart-ec2-instance-from-cloudwatch-alarm)). In my case however, I don't think that Auto Scaling is a viable option; because of licensing restrictions on some other software running on the instance.

I'm running a windows based EC2 instance.

Thanks,
Yug

Comment: Would it be easier to monitor if the application is running or not and attempt to restart on a set interval if it is not? That would also cover other recovery scenarios not just related to cloudwatch alarms.

Comment: @Jason.  This might be an option, but I think would necessarily entail writing a monitoring script which checks the CPU usage on a set interval and tracks if this is below a set threshold for n minutes (basically the function that Cloud Watch performs, so easier if there is a way to simply catch that event).  Also, I don't want a trigger event if say the application was never started (eg. i'm doing some maintenance work on the instance).  All possible, but hoping there's an easier solution. Thanks

Comment: Essentially, to do automated actions with Cloudwatch, you need a script/service monitoring an SQS queue. Which is probably more complicated than monitoring the service directly.

Comment: @datasage.  What about the new Lambda service, or is that also likely a more complicated route?  I couldn't see in the documentation if is configurable with Cloudfront events.

Comment: From what I understand Lamba is a service to run workers that can be relatively isolated. Like an image conversion system based on files uploaded to s3. Your problem is not really what its intended to solve.

Comment: Suggestions thus far are pointing me towards the (easier) approach of directly monitoring the application via a timer.  If I understand correctly it should work something like this; Run a script on a timer sequence (say every 15 seconds - from task scheduler or a dotnet app?).  The script checks CPU level > threshold (how?) and pastes timestamp to a text file.  If threshold CPU level has not been met for > n minutes then script restarts the application.  If anyone can help add detail to this implementation as a proposed answer, then i'll run with that.

Answer (score 0):

An **AWS CloudWatch** alarm can be used to trigger:

- An auto scaling policy (eg add/remove instances in an auto scaling group)
- Stop / Terminate an EC2 instance
- Send a notification via **Amazon Simple Notification Service (SNS)**

SNS can then send the notification to subscribers in various formats:

- Send an SMS (USA only)
- Push a message to an HTTP/S endpoint (eg an application you have written)
- Push a message to an Amazon Simple Queue Service (SQS)
- Send a notification to mobile device (eg Android, iPhone)

Based on your scenario, the HTTP or SQS notifications could be used, but you would have to write a program to respond to the notifications. However, you would only be using a proxy for your app's health (eg CPU Utilization) rather than actually monitoring the health of your app.

You can send a Custom Metric from an application to CloudWatch and then configure an alarm to trigger based on this Custom Metric. But, if you're going to all that trouble, then the code that detects the problem should probably fix it directly, rather than going via CloudWatch.